# Search people with Google+ API

Tags: search, google-plus

I have a several problem with Google+ API.

When I do a search, for example of my name: "Ismael" with the API

(you can do it with this URL): https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/search

Google+ returns 50 results per page, and give a `nextPageToken` to see the next page. But when see 6 or 7 pages, always is the same token and I can't see more people.

In summary, I want to get for example 10000 or more results in a search, and I can just get less than 300. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Once there are no more results being returned and the nextPageToken matches the pageToken returned you can assume there are no more results. There just are not 10000 results for you to get.

Comment: My name is Ismael, and if I search Ismael, I am not in the results... Thus, the search is incomplete.